# Storing a lot of text in one value whose column is varchar (Database)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a very simple textbox in a front end application (like php although the language doesn't matter) and is inserting into the description column in a table in the Database defined below:

Table (ID[primary key], description[varchar(255)])

Although it will not happen often, at times there will be a need to insert more than 255 characters for one tuple. I could increase the length of the varchar but there are restrictions for the tuple size so to play it safe kept it at the recommended maximum 255.

The only way I could figure out how to do this would be to have 2 tables and split the text up into 255 character pieces. Tables defined as:

Table1 (ID[primary key]..........)

Table2 (ID, table1ID[foreign key to table 1] description[varchar(255)])

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Edit: Mysql version 5.5.11
Wasn't aware there was a text data type. Probably new. Sounds like a type of application object but is it flexible enough to on average store 150 characters and 10% of the times store close to 5000 characters?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: are you looking for mysql 'text' data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using MySQL version 5.0.3 or later, you can just increase the size of your `VARCHAR`.  According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> Values in `VARCHAR` columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a `VARCHAR` in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used. See [Section E.7.4, “Table Column-Count and Row-Size Limits”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

To do this you would do:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY description VARCHAR(...) [NOT] NULL;
```

Or you could use the [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html) type:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY description TEXT [NOT] NULL;
```

Comment: TEXT has same limits as VARCHAR 65,535 .

Comment: @DhruvPathak: Yes, but it is the only solution (short of splitting the data) on MySQL <5.0.3.

Comment: "MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535" - its 0-65,535 bytes for the entire tuple so still a restriction since 3 bytes make up one character.

Comment: @D.Rattansingh: 3 bytes make up one character??  What character encoding are you using?  (For the English alphabet at least, it would be a very uncommon encoding that used >1 byte/character).

Comment: @D.Rattansingh:  What language is the text?

Comment: english. I am incorrect. Just quickly read that in the mysql documentation and assumed was for all characters. Thanks.